# Can't mount the dmg image with the user agreement

Tags: macos, dmg-image

I am currently using macOS installed on an external disk. In general, I can open dmg files and mount them successfully. However, when it comes to dmg files with user agreements that require manual consent, they often fail to mount. A popup window appears with the message 'Failed to open disk image. Operation not permitted.' Even when I try to manually mount them using hdutil, I still receive the 'Operation not permitted' error. In the Disk Utility, I briefly see an image named 'apple udif read-only compressed (bzip2) media' but it quickly disappears.